# Static call method in Dart Classes (make Classes callable)

Tags: function, class, call, dart

For an embedded DSL I want classes to behave like a function. It seems easy for instances (https://www.dartlang.org/articles/emulating-functions/) but I couldn't make it happen for classes. I tried creating a static call a method but this didn't work either.

Is there a way or do I have to give the class another name and make Pconst a function, calling the constructor?

```dart
class Pconst {
  final value;
  Pconst(this.value);
  static Pconst call(value) => new Pconst(value);

  String toString() => "Pconst($value)";
}

void main() {
  var test = Pconst(10);
  // Breaking on exception: Class '_Type' has no instance method 'call'.

  print("Hello, $test");
}
```

Comment: Why do you need Pconst to be a class?
You could create a top level function 
Pconst(value) {
 return new PconstImpl(value).call(value);
}

I must admit that I don't fully understand what you want to achieve.
Can you provide more information please?

Comment: I'm aware of the possibility to create a top level function in addition to the class but I don't really want to clutter my namespace, I'd prefer to have the Class and the Function/Callable Class to have the same name.

Comment: Why do you need a class at all? IMHO that makes only sense if you have a parameterized instance where you call call(x) on. The way you use it you could use a function as well (without a class at all).

Comment: I basically want to have a constructor where I don't need the new keyword, so the class does make sense. I probably will go with another top level function calling the constructor. Hoped there was a shortcut :/. Thanks anyways!

Comment: constructor where you don't need the new key word, but using `new` signifies its a constructor, it sounds like you don't know whether you want a basic function or a constructor, if you want a function that creates a new object then just create a stand alone function that wraps around a constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try something like this:

```
class _PConst{
    final value;
    _Pconst(this.value);

    String toString() => "Pconst($value)";
}

PConst(value){
    return new _PConst(value);
}

void main() {
    var test = Pconst(10);

    print("Hello, $test"); //should work ok
}
```

so your basically just hiding/wrapping your classes constructor behind a bog standard function.

Answer (score 9):

```
class TestA {
  call(int a, int b) => a + b;
}

void main()
  var TA = new TestA();

  int integer = TA(3, 4);
  print (integer); 
}
```

The `call()` method is **special**, in that anyone who defines a `call()` method is presumed to dynamically emulate a function. This allows us to use instances of `TestA` as if they were functions that take two integer arguments.

Comment: Hi, I was aware of the call method and how it can be used for instances. I'm looking if there's a way to create directly callable classes.

Comment: directly callable classes... sounds like a function like everyone else has been saying in the comments for the question