# Use constructor as function

Tags: dart

I know I can use static and instance methods as "functions" by referring to them by name (`MyClass.staticMethod` or `myObj.instanceMethod`).  Is there a way to do the same with constructors?

For example, given:

```
class MyClass {
    final double val;
    final String name;

    MyClass.fromSomethingElse(SomethingElse se) : val = se.score, name = se.description;
}
```

Can I use the `fromSomethingElse` constructor as a stream converter (argument to `map()`)?  If so, is there any way to use non-named constructors that way, too?

I know I can always define a function to do this:

```
MyClass mapper(SomethingElse se) => new MyClass.fromSomethingElse(se);
```

But it seems needlessly verbose.

Comment: this is the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20372328/static-call-method-in-dart-classes-make-classes-callable

Comment: Well, not really the same question, but from the answer to that other question, I gather the answer to my question is "no".  I would need to add a function, or `call()` method, to delegate to the constructor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Static call method in Dart Classes (make Classes callable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20372328/static-call-method-in-dart-classes-make-classes-callable)

Comment: On this site, questions are duplicates if the **answer** is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update**

This feature was removed again and is planned to be added in a new approach later.
Follow https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/10659

**original**

Closzurization of constructors is already supported in bleeding edge

```
void main() {
  var constructor = new SomeClass#someConstructor;
  var x = constructor();

  print(dateConstructor(isUtc: true)(2000,1,1));
  print(dateConstructor(isUtc: false)(2000,1,1));
}

Function dateConstructor({bool isUtc}) {
  if(isUtc) {
    return new DateTime#utc;
  } else {
    return new DateTime#;
  }
}

class SomeClass {
  SomeClass.someConstructor() {
    print('constructing...');
  }
}
```

prints

> constructing...
>   2000-01-01 00:00:00.000Z
>   2000-01-01 00:00:00.000

I still get analyzer warnings for `#` though.

Comment: Hm, what's the SO policy on this? The previously accepted answer was correct at the time of accepting, but now this answer is correct (and better), given the current state of the language.

Comment: Don't worry too much. Both ways are fine. Later readers can decide for themselves which solution is the better fit for their problem. I think Alans answer is still valid.

Comment: @Darky right, that was removed a while ago. They plan to make a new attempt eventually.

Comment: I guess it's still removed? Is there an issue to track the progress of this?

Answer (score 4):

now you can use it after dart 2.15.0

> see https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/216#issuecomment-972537327

you can use it like:

```
class OBool {
  final bool b;
  OBool(this.b);
}

...

OBool Function(bool) myBool = OBool.new;
```

if you want to use it on your project you can edit your `pubspec.yaml` to this:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.15.0 <3.0.0'
```

good luck!

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't. But you might be able to in the future. See https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=10659 , "Be able to closurize constructors"

You can closurize static methods, so if you defined

```
static fromSE(se) => new MyClass.fromSomethingElse(se);
```

then you could write

```
[1, 2, 3].map(MyClass.fromSE);
```

Or you could just write a method as you describe.